# Springboot not loading application.dev.properties file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

In my project I want to use environment specific property file. For example if I am running it into development it should use application.dev.properties, for production it should use application.prod.properties and so on.

I have below two files in my resources folder.

1. application.properties  (For production)
2. application.dev.properties  (For development)

I have one properties like below in each file.

For Prod

```
server.database.host=192.168.1.1
```

For Dev

```
server.database.host=192.168.12.125
```

And I have a class like below

```
 public class DataSource {

     @Value(${server.database.host})
     String host;
```

The above code always takes prod setting (application.properties) file even though I supply proper argument for dev like `--spring.profiles.active=dev`

Below is the command I am using to load the dev properties file.

```
java -jar myjar.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev
```

It also prints that active profile is dev but it always connect to prod db.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A few issues I noticed:

1. `@Value` property name should be a `String` like `@Value("${server.database.host}")`
2. Profile specific property files should follow `application-{profile}.properties` format, e.g. `application-dev.properties`
3. Try passing the profile with `-D` like `java -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -jar app.jar`

Comment: Hey thanks.. I changed the properties file name as you suggested and then the command you suggested in step 3 worked well.. Thank you so much..!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work any more for SpringBoot 2.0.

Answer (score 11):

Try adding a vm argument in the run configuration:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

Answer (score 6):

You are supposed to specify which profile to run with as follows:

```sh
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=foo,bar
```

Also see documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/run-profiles.html

Answer (score 2):

If running on Eclipse or STS, then use following steps:

1. Right click on project -> Run As -> Run Configuration.
2. In the new window, select spring boot application on left side, and add details on the right and in the profile dropdown, select dev.
   [image]
3. Click apply and run.

Comment: after right click, there is no spring boot application option.  please mention your screenshots clearly